# How to check if last 4 digits of value is in a range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a column where each value is 9 characters (col1). I need to pull the last 4 characters of col1 and see if the value is in the range of 0001 - 0879. There could be letters in this string.

Initial table

```
col1       column2
585550529  red
589960MNO  blue
849828415  green
```

Expected result

```
col1       column2  column3
585550529  red      True
589960MNO  blue     False
849828415  green    False

SELECT col1, 
       col2, 
       CASE WHEN RIGHT(col1,4) IN('0001','0002','0003') THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
FROM table
```

Is there anyway to do this without having to type all 879 strings within the IN statement? This is going to get ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BETWEEN

```
...
CASE WHEN RIGHT(col1,4) between  '0001' and '0879' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
...
```

Comment: @MartyB Yes it does

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
SELECT col1, 
       col2, 
       CASE WHEN 
         isnumeric(RIGHT(col1,4)) and 
         cast(RIGHT(col1,4) as int) between 0 and 879
           THEN 'true' 
           ELSE 'false' 
       END
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Using PATINDEX

```
;WITH CTE(col1,column2)
AS
(
SELECT '585550529','red' UNION ALL
SELECT '589960MNO','blue' UNION ALL
SELECT '849828415','green'
)
SELECT col1,column2,CASE WHEN  newcol BETWEEN 1 AND  0879 THEN  'True'  ELSE 'False'  END AS column3
FROM
(
SELECT col1,
      column2,
      CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[A-Z a-z]%',RIGHT(col1,4)) = 0 THEN RIGHT(col1,4)  ELSE ' '  END AS INT) newcol,
      CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[A-Z a-z]%',RIGHT(col1,4)) = 0 THEN 'True'  ELSE 'False'  END  getcol

FROM CTE
) Dt
```

Result

```
col1        column2 column3
----------------------------
585550529   red     True
589960MNO   blue    False
849828415   green   False
```